# How to generate JUnit Report along with along with allure report generated by using allure-mocha?

Tags: javascript, typescript, junit, mocha.js, allure

In a typescript test-only project which uses Mocha framework to run the tests, `allure-mocha` to generate an allure report, I am trying to generate a junit report along with the allure report.

I tried using `mocha-junit-reporter` library. Modified my `mocharc.js` as below, but I keep getting the error `MochaAllure: "step" can't be used in parallel mode! To use Allure Runtime API, please, switch back to single thread mode`. I am NOT running tests in parallel mode, and I have also updated jobs to 1 in the moacharc.js file, and also marked parallel: false in the file.

I do not get any error when I run the tests only with `allure-mocha` library, but get this error if I add the `mocha-junit-reporter` to it.

mochar.js

```
module.exports = {
    spec: './dist/**/*.js',
    jobs: 1,
    timeout: 300000,
    require: 'dotenv/config',
    reporter: ['allure-mocha', 'mocha-junit-reporter'],
    reporterOptions: {
        mochaFile: './test-results.xml'
    },
    parallel: false
};
```